# AWK - match multiple patterns and print results in one line

Tags: awk

Using my limited scripting knowledge.. I have put together an expect script to run some commands on specific devices. The output is below and is saved from all devices to a file (I just listed 2 devices as an example).

```
  Current State  : Active
Router1slot1# showstats
  Active  stats             : 31
  Active  stats1            : 47
Router1slot1# exit
  Current State  : Standby
Router1slot2# showstats
  Active  stats             : 59
  Active  stats1            : 56
Router1slot2# exit
```

What I would like is to get some values from the output and have them displayed in rows, delimited by "," :

```
Router1slot1,Active,31,47
Router1slot2,Standby,59,56
```

I got a step closer to what I want using :

```
cat switch.log | awk '/# show/ {print substr($1,1)} /State  :/ {print substr($4,1)} /: / {print substr($5,1)}' >> awk.csv

Output:

Active

Router1slot1#
31
47
Standby

Router1slot2#
59
56
```

From here I tried different options to convert rows to columns, but it doesn't seem to work. The output is similar to:

```
56uter1slot2#59
```

Is there any (more efficient) way to get the required format?

Comment: Hi,Did any of the following answers helped you ? If they does than plese accept/upvote  the answer by ticking the right sign besides the answer.  If they do not help, please explain what is expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using given data below one should work, assuming there will not be any empty lines

**Input**

```
$ cat file
Current State  : Active
Router1slot1# showstats
  Active  stats             : 31
  Active  stats1            : 47
Router1slot1# exit
  Current State  : Standby
Router1slot2# showstats
  Active  stats             : 59
  Active  stats1            : 56
Router1slot2# exit
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -F'[#:]' -v OFS=, '/exit/{print r,s; r=s=""; next}/showstats/{r=$1;next}{s=(s?s OFS:"")$2}' file
Router1slot1, Active, 31, 47
Router1slot2, Standby, 59, 56
```

**Explanation**

```
awk -F'[#:]' -v OFS=, '             # call awk set and input and ouptut field sep
    /exit/{                         # if exit word found in record
            print r,s;              # print variable r, and s
            r=s="";                 # set variable r and s to null
            next                    # stop processing go to next line
    }
    /showstats/{                    # if showstats found
            r=$1;                   # copy first column to variable r
            next                    # stop processing go to next line
   }
   {
      s=(s?s OFS:"")$2              # variable s contains 2nd field of each line 
                                    # (which is not skipped above using next), 
                                    # if s was set before then concatenate
                                    # s with current record 2nd field, 
                                    # where separator being OFS between 
                                    # them (OFS=output field separator)
   }' file
```

Comment: This is very useful, thanks! is there a way to make it work if I would have an empty line after every "Router1slotx# exit" ?

Comment: @dxxbstu: just modify `{s=` to `NF{s=`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk  ' BEGIN{RS="# exit";OFS=","}{$1=$1} length($0){gsub(/#/,"",$5);print $5,$4,$10,$14}' input
Router1slot1,Active,31,47
Router1slot2,Standby,59,56
```

This will divide the text into records separated by `# exit` and then print the selected columns as per requirement. 
`gsub` is to remove the pound sign from the slot number field. 
`length($0)` is to weed out blank lines from the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
awk -F':' '{ORS=(NR%5==0?RS:FS)}1' f|awk -F'[:# ]+' '{print $5,$4,$9,$12}' OFS=,
Router1slot1,Active,31,47
Router1slot2,Standby,59,56
```